# Install msi using Start-Process with /q switch?

Tags: powershell

I want to install an msi with a `/q` switch, I look online and the examples don't have the `/q` switch and I keep getting errors.

I need something like:

```
$WorkingDirectory = (Split-Path $myinvocation.mycommand.path -Parent)

Start-Process -FilePath msiexec /i "$WorkingDirectory\LAPS.x64.msi" -ArgumentList /q
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with `Start-Process`. Use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators):

```
& msiexec.exe /i "$WorkingDirectory\LAPS.x64.msi" /q
```

Answer (score 0):

put the whole command in the brackets

Example(Python msi):

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList "/I $($LocalPython.FullName) /passive ALLUSERS=1 ADDLOCAL=Extensions"
```

replace `/passive` with `/q`

Answer (score 0):

Not all installers are the same. To find the installer switches for your .msi use:

```
.\LAPS.x64.msi /?
.\LAPS.x64.msi -?
```

I would also store the `msi` path in a variable, and use an `ArrayList` for the arguments, something like this has worked for me in my scripts:

```
# Path to .msi
$msiPath= 'C:\LAPS.x64.msi'

# Define arguments
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arguments = 
@("/i `"$msiPath`"",
"/quiet")

# Start installation
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "$arguments" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$path="C:\Dat\install.msi"
$parameters="/q"

$packageinstall=(split-path $path -leaf) + ' ' + $parameters 
write-host $packageinstall
$computers = get-content c:\com.txt

$computers | where{test-connection $_ -quiet -count 1} | ForEach-Object {

    copy-item $path "\\$_\c$\windows\temp" -Force -Recurse 
    $newProc=([WMICLASS]"\\$_\root\cimv2:win32_Process").Create("C:\windows\temp\$packageinstall")

    If ($newProc.ReturnValue -eq 0) {
        Write-Host $_ $newProc.ProcessId
    } else {
        write-host $_ Process create failed with $newProc.ReturnValue
    }
}
```